# Как вызвать правильно функцию с двумя @escaping: func example(completion1: @escaping (SomeClass) -> (), completion2: @escaping (AnotherClass) -> () )

Tags: swift, xcode

Не могу понять как вызвать функцию с двумя @escaping

Comment: а в чем проблема какой-то tuple вернуть?

Comment: да вот не получается, @Andrew . Пишет, что формат вызова некорректный какой-то. Можете пример написать вызова указанной мной функции через тюпл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример

```
func example(completion1: @escaping (String) -> (), completion2: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    completion1("test 1")
    completion2("test 2")
}

example { str1 in
    print(str1)
} completion2: { str2 in
    print(str2)
}
```

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение, уловил смысл. почему-то пробую так, но не совсем получается. Возможно, это связано с тем, что у меня сейчас в программе функция принимает 1 значение, а через @escaping убегает еще три. В общем я в изучении) Спасибо.